# jquery .Hover is being called each time mouse is moved

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I have a feeling this is being caused by how my function is setup, but each time the mouse is moved over the element, the hover event is being called multiple times (I only want the event to be called when the mouse is hovered over the element, and when the mouse leaves the element (and therefore no longer over it).

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#about-us-facebook-default').hover(
     function(){
     $(this).css({'display':'none'});
     $('#about-us-facebook-hover').css({'display':'block'});
},
function(){
     $(this).stop(true,true).css({'display':'block'});
     $('#about-us-facebook-hover').css({'display':'none'});

}
);

});
```

The layout:

```
<div class="about-contact-button">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/BlackTiePhotographers" id="about-us-facebook-hover" >
<img src="http://blacktiephotographers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/facebook-hover.png" alt="" title="Connect with us on Facebook" width="30" height="30" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2267" /></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/BlackTiePhotographers" id="about-us-facebook-default">
<img src="http://blacktiephotographers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/facebook.png" alt="Join Black Tie Photographers on Facebook" title="Connect with us on Facebook" width="30" height="30" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2266" /></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/BlackTiePhotographers">Join on Facebook</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#about-us-facebook-default').mouseover(function(){
         $(this).css({'display':'none'});
         $('#about-us-facebook-hover').css({'display':'inline-block'});          
    });
    $('#about-us-facebook-hover').mouseout(function(){
        $('#about-us-facebook-default').stop(true,true).css({'display':'inline-block'});
        $(this).css({'display':'none'});
    });
});
```

But if I can give you an advice you must do that in css it is simple and quite lite.

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wh7vW/2/) you can find the two solutions.

Comment: Finally I discourage you to use javascript for this for one reason, if your pointer go over too fast on the image the event mouseout isn't catch. I test with mouseleave and mouseenter and the result is similar.

Answer (score 2):

You are hiding the element from within the mouse enter method, which causes the mouse to leave the element again, which in turn causes the element to be shown again. This repeats, causing the behavior you observed.

You will probably want to attach the handler to the outer div and handle the visibilities there.